# How can i Get 5 Volt output with GPIO

Tags: raspbian, rpi.gpio, pi-3b+

I am using Raspberry Pi 3 B+ and I want to run a 5 volt DC motor with `RPi.GPIO`, I have written a code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from pip._vendor.distlib.compat import raw_input

u = raw_input('how many volt: ')
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(32, True)

while u == '5':
    GPIO.output(32, GPIO.HIGH)
```

When I run this code Error an Showing:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/home/pi/Documents/5v.py", line 8
    GPIO.setup(32, GPIO.OUT)
RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
```

When I fix this Error:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
from pip._vendor.distlib.compat import raw_input

u = raw_input('how many volt: ')
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

GPIO.setup(32, GPIO.OUT)


while u == '5':
    GPIO.output(32, True)
```

Error is not coming but the problem is motor is not running.
Can anyone help me, I am using Python2.7.15 .

Answer (score 3):

The Raspberry Pi has two 5V pins but they're always on. There are also 3V3 pins which are always on, but the ones marked 'GPIO' on pinout diagrams (e.g. https://pinout.xyz - or type `pinout` at the command line) are variable 3V3 - you can configure them

To control a 5V supply with a GPIO pin, use a transistor. The way a transistor works is when it receives input (say 3V3 from a GPIO pin), it outputs another voltage (provided by another source). There's a decent explanation of how that works here: https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/balloon-pi-tay-popper/7

I would also suggest you use GPIO Zero instead of RPi.GPIO. You'll find it much simpler to read, write and understand. Use the `OutputDevice` class - shown two steps on in the above link. See https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io for more info.

Comment: This answer provides good advice, but the "explanation" of transistor function is seriously misleading. Bipolar transistors are current controlled devices and do not "output" anything - they control current flow (which can, of course, be in a higher voltage circuit).

Comment: Absolutely - I have edited accordingly

Answer (score 1):

The GPIO operate at 3.3V and can safely source 16mA which is unlikely to run a motor - even then you need additional components to protect the Pi from back EMF.

You can control a motor using a transistor or FET See https://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Interface_Circuits

Answer (score 0):

Search for a TXB0104 level shifter.
It is a bi-directional level shifter
that can translate +3.3v pulses to
+5.0v pulses.
I use it for a +5v stepper motor control.
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11771